# Alternatives to "perl -e" command

Tags: string, perl, terminal, system

I am using the "perl -e" command to produce string output file for instance:

```
> perl -e 'print "A"x5'
AAAAA
```

Which are the alternatives to this command?

Don't ask me why but I don't like this command and I can't find other similar.

Comment: you can use python instead perl !

Comment: I ask why you don't like `perl -e` so I can better understand what you do like.  Why don't you like it?

Comment: @sputnick don't know what he want. but I given just an idea.

Comment: You'll have to tell us what you don't like about the command.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
perl -E 'say "A"x5'
```

or :

```
perl<<!
print "A"x5
!
```

or

```
echo 'print "A"x5' | perl
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a short shell script to eliminate the -e part.

```
$ cat perle
#!/bin/sh

perl -e "$@"
```

Which lets you write `perle 'print "Hello"'`.  The quotes are still necessary.

Or you can use [Devel::REPL](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aREPL) and its `re.pl`.

```
$ re.pl
$ "A"x5
AAAAA
```

These are just shots in the dark, what do you dislike about `perl -e`?